# How can I effectively block sequences in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, sequence, updates, atomic

I have two threads, both these threads are trying to block 20 items form a sequence in postgres.

Following query works perfectly fine when there is no concurrency:

```
select last_value + 1 as start_seq,
  setval('sequence_name',
         (select last_value + 20 from sequence_name)) as end_seq
from sequence_name

If sequence's last value is 100, 
Thread T1 will get start_seq as 101 and end_seq as 120
Thread T2 will get start_seq as 121 and end_seq as 140
[considering T1 is started after T2]
```

Now assume two threads are trying to block 20 items at the same time. It is possible that both T1 and T2 set start_seq as 101 and end_seq as 120.

**Is there a wayout using which I can block sequences atomically?**

I tried using 'update with select' using 'RETURNING' keyword:

```
update sequence_name
  set last_value = last_value + 20
returning last_value - 20 + 1, last_value;
```

But it throws an error - 'cannot change sequence 'sequence_name'', which essentially means you cannot update a sequence using **update clause**.

Comment: You can define the sequence with a `cache` value of 20 - the cached values are specific to the connection, so if one transaction (=connection) obtains one value, it will implicitly advance the sequence by the cache size, giving the next connection a value of "cache size" + 1

Answer (score -1):

There is no need to *reserve* anything. Sequences in PostgreSQL present non-transactonal behavior. Each invocation of `nextval` will consume at least one ID, irreversibly.

To get next N numbers from a sequence, just call the `nextval` function N times. Like here:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import psycopg2

def get_numbers_from_pg_sequence(cur, seq_name, limit):
    numbers = []
    while len(numbers) < limit:
        cur.execute("SELECT nextval(%s)", [seq_name])
        r = cur.fetchone()
        numbers.append(r[0])
    return numbers

with psycopg2.connect("dbname=test") as con:
    with con.cursor() as cur:
        cur.execute("CREATE SEQUENCE IF NOT EXISTS myseq")
        lst = get_numbers_from_pg_sequence(cur, "myseq", 5)
        print(lst)
```

If you need to run `nextval` very frequently (like, thousands per second) then you could `ALTER` the sequence to have `CACHE` parameter set to more than default value of 1, and get some minor optimization at a cost of "wasting" many numbers from sequence even if you run `nextval` only once in a session.

Note there is *no guarantee* of consecutive allocation - in some circumstances you may get non-consecutive sequence of unique numbers, even in one transaction.

**Must read**: notes in the bottom of [CREATE SEQUENCE documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createsequence.html).

Comment: The issue with this approach is that I want consecutive sequences.

Comment: @deadcode then you need something different, quote:  *sequence objects* ***cannot be used*** *if “gapless” assignment of sequence numbers is needed. It is possible to build gapless assignment by using exclusive locking of a table containing a counter; but this solution is much more expensive than sequence objects, especially if many transactions need sequence numbers concurrently.*

Comment: Thanks @filiprem for your reply, this will help